# Centos7 libvirt permission issues qcow2 images

Tags: centos, kvm, libvirt

This is all on a clean install of Centos7.  Installed from minimal image, updated and then the following guide followed.

Following this guide:

https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-install-kvm-on-centos-7-rhel-7-headless-server/

Resulting with this:

```
  ERROR    Error: --disk path=/var/lib/libvirt/images/labserver1_vm_disk1_40g,bus=virtio,format=qcow2: Could not start storage │drwxr-xr-x.  2 bruce bruce    6 Jun 18 18:11 Pictures
pool: cannot open directory '/var/lib/libvirt/images': Permission denied
```

From this command:

```
> virt-install 
> --virt-type=kvm 
> --name labserver1 
> --ram 2048 
> --vcpus=1 
> --os-variant=centos7.0 
> --cdrom=/home/bruce/distro_images/CentOS-7-x86_64-Minimal-1810.iso 
> --network=bridge=br0,model=virtio 
> --graphics vnc 
> --disk path=/var/lib/libvirt/images/labserver1_vm_disk1_40g,bus=virtio,format=qcow2
```

Ok this is obviously a permission issue.  From what I've read having that file in  /var/lib/libvirt/images should take care of the issue.

I used this to create the disk file.

```
  sudo qemu-img create -f qcow2 /var/lib/libvirt/images/labserver1_vm_disk1_40g 40g
```

That all being said.

Is this due to me doing something wrong? If so what?    I did some googling and didn't find any "libvirt / kvm directory permission" articles. If the files are in the right place then I shouldn't be having permission issues.

If I have to use sudo to create the disk file I can see then why qemu would have an issue opening it, but I can't create it without.

Should I be creating the files differently?  I also saw articles referencing changing qemu.conf to have it run as root, which I don't like.

I feel like I'm missing a step here or something permission based.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you choose not to run `virt-install` with `sudo` then you have to specify a connection string to use the system libvirtd instance, rather than creating a VM under your user account.

```
virt-install --connect qemu:///system ...
```

or

```
sudo virt-install ...
```

Comment: Is one of those considered better practice than the other?

Comment: @TheEditor It depends. The first one depends on [using PolicyKit](https://serverfault.com/a/739614/126632) to allow a non-root user to manage libvirt without sudo. PolicyKit provides more fine-grained control than sudo does, but it is another thing running on the system.

Comment: Ok thank you.  This was a big help.   I just couldn't find a definitive answer online.

Answer (score 0):

In my Debian 10.4 the virt-install is lauched with **libvirt** user but after I see the disk creation is done with **libvirt-qemu** user.

This is my Specific list packages installed:

```
qemu-kvm
qemu-system
qemu-utils
libvirt-clients
libvirt-daemon-system
python-libvirt
virtinst
```

I can see this libvirt-qemu user when I putted `777` rights in my path /opt/test01.

Cordially